# Как узнать разрешение экрана на JAVA Android

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
Display display1 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display1.getRealSize(size);
        int scrWidth = size.x;
        int scrHeight = size.y;
```

Но это значения без учета размера Тулбара. А как узнать размеры свободной области?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964368/how-can-i-get-the-screen-height-pixel-without-status-bar-actionbar ?

Comment: Все понял! Благодарю!

Comment: Я тогда отправлю как ответ, чтобы пригодилось другим гостям этого поста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить высоту статус-бара с помощью кода:

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
int statusBarTop = rectangle.top;
int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int statusbarHeight = Math.abs(statusBarTop - contentViewTop);
```

Что касается экшен-бара, то у него есть константа `abs__action_bar_default_height`, можно копнуть к ее сторону.

И теперь, когда вы знаете высоту статус-бара, можно сделать вот так:

```
mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
        int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
        int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
        int statusbarHeight = Math.abs(statusBarHeight - contentViewTop);

        int[] location = {0,0};
        mMainLayout.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        int actionbarheight = Math.abs(location[0] -statusBarHeight);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, actionbarheight + "", 1).show();
    }
});
```

---

<sub>[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964368/how-can-i-get-the-screen-height-pixel-without-status-bar-actionbar)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Высоту СтатусБара можно узнать вот так:

```
 Rect rectangle = new Rect();
 Window window = activity.getWindow();
 window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
 int statusBarTop = rectangle.top;
 int contentViewTop =    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
 int statusbarHeight = Math.abs(statusBarTop - contentViewTop);
```

Останется вычесть из высоты всего экрана, высоту СтатусБара. 
Благодарю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193683/denis за подсказку.